# Spring Boot 3.x app is initializing same bean multiple times

Tags: spring-boot

I apologize up front, I won't be able to provide a trivial example because it's a complicated app and my employer (like many) would just lose their mind if I "exposed" their "proprietary software", but...

I have some tests in my project. When I try to run one of the tests, the app is somehow trying to initialize the same bean more than once. What I mean is, if I put a breakpoint in the constructor of the bean, it gets hit at least twice, but it shouldn't. If I try to force it to be a singleton or remove it entirely, the problem moves to a different bean, so it's systemic, it's not a problem with this bean specifically.

I must stress: There are NO Spring errors being logged during this. My searches here and on the greater internet have mostly resulted in hits involving errors from the Spring and/or Spring Boot framework regarding multiple or duplicate definitions, but I'm not getting any of that. It just hits the same one twice. That bean errors out at that point, which takes down the app (as it should).

The stack trace is pretty useless; I've tried to see what I could discern about bean ordering or similar, but I don't know how to get that. There are countless answered questions regarding how to get a list of registered beans; that's not helpful, because I can't even get that far.

I know that this is terribly vague, but has anyone seen anything like this? Any tips on how I could diagnose further?

Comment: The actual error is `Failed to load ApplicationContext for [WebMergedContextConfiguration@xxxxxxxx testClass = <my test class>`

Comment: Multiple bean instantiation usually means a poorly usage of the beans throughout your application. It is possible that you have circular dependencies. So the first step I would suggest is to annotate the beans in error with `@Lazy` and later on do a seek and refactor as to avoid those circular dependencies. It is not clear on your question if that is an application runtime error or UNIT test error. If it is at unit test error I would look for whatever you are using mockedStatic as multiple usage of it can sometimes lead to such problems, in that context the approach is to divide and conquer...

Comment: Mark some of the classes/tests as ignored and see which one makes your application to not fail. It will not be that one, probably something that started before it.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, the app isn't doing what I thought. The problem was that the application was crashing/erroring, but I didn’t have sufficient logging in place to see that. Once I installed a logback-spring.xml with STDOUT actually going somewhere, I could see the other crash (something that was unexpected and elsewhere in the code).

But what is causing the multiple loads is that the app is crashing, but then doing some kind of zombie restart where it seems to be starting over, but something is still there from the previous run. Maybe it’s like one thread is crashing and restarting, but some other thread(s) remained. I get the `CONDITIONS EVALUATION REPORT` each time it “crashes”, followed by the startup messages (even including the ASCII art banner that we’d created).

Is there some way to disable this behavior? If it crashes, we want it to, well, crash.